# How to skip first array element from being updated in collection?

Tags: mongodb

How to skip first element from being updated in nested array.

Below code works to update all item except first from items array based on order property. But wanted to update all except first item(with any order) as order may starts from any number.

```
db.contents.updateMany(  
{ "contentType": "element-specification", "locale": "en-NZ" },
{ $set: { "sections.$[element].data.0.items.$[item].canDelete": true }},  
{ arrayFilters: [{ "element.sectionTitle": "Test" }, { "item.order": { $ne: 0 }}]});
```

Sample document collection:

```
{
    "contentType": "element-specification",
    "locale": "en-NZ",
    "sections": [
        {
            "sectionTitle": "Test",
            "formLayout": "multi-column",
            "data": [
                {
                    "category": "dynamicItems",
                    "type": "textbox",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "options",
                            "label": "Label 00",
                            "order": 0,
                            "canDelete": false
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "options",
                            "label": "Label 01",
                            "order": 1,
                            "canDelete": false
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "options",
                            "label": "Label 03",
                            "order": 3,
                            "canDelete": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "sectionTitle": "Test2",
            "formLayout": "multi-column",
            "data": [
                {
                    "category": "dynamicItems",
                    "type": "textbox",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "options",
                            "label": "Label 17",
                            "order": 17,
                            "canDelete": false
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "options",
                            "label": "Label 18",
                            "order": 18,
                            "canDelete": false
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "options",
                            "label": "Label 19",
                            "order": 19,
                            "canDelete": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Eg. All item's `canDelete` property should be updated to `true` in `items` array except first item i.e. expectation is to update 2 items with order 1 & 3 in items array by skipping first item with order 0.

Don't wanted filter based on property but using 1st array element so that order property doesn't matter.

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.